# How to make Start button start the game?

Tags: java, swing

im making this one game and i have menu created for it that opens first when starting the program but the menu buttons wont do anything. How do i link this menu window to the game so that when i press "new game" the game starts?

P.S
Yes i did try to find solution from several youtube videos and javas own help site but i couldnt find how to link button click action to start up action in game so that it basicly opens up game screen and starts the game.

All kind of help would be appreciated!

Code:

```
 public class Menu {
JTextArea output;
JScrollPane scrollPane;

public JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu menu, submenu;
    JMenuItem menuItem;
    JRadioButtonMenuItem rbMenuItem;
    JCheckBoxMenuItem cbMenuItem;

    //Create the menu bar.
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    //Build the first menu.
    menu = new JMenu("Menu");
    menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
            "The only menu in this program that has menu items");
    menuBar.add(menu);

    //a group of JMenuItems
    menuItem = new JMenuItem("New Game",
                             KeyEvent.VK_T);
    //menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T); //used constructor instead
    menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
            KeyEvent.VK_1, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
    menuItem.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
            "This doesn't really do anything");
    menu.add(menuItem);

    ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("");
    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Score history", icon);
    menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    menu.add(menuItem);

    menuItem = new JMenuItem(icon);
    menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    menu.add(menuItem);

    //a submenu
    menu.addSeparator();
    submenu = new JMenu("Options");
    submenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);

    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Sounds");
    menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
            KeyEvent.VK_2, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
    submenu.add(menuItem);

    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit Game");
    submenu.add(menuItem);
    menu.add(submenu);

    //Build second menu in the menu bar.


    return menuBar;
}

public Container createContentPane() {
    //Create the content-pane-to-be.
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);

    //Create a scrolled text area.
    output = new JTextArea(5, 30);
    output.setEditable(false);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(output);

    //Add the text area to the content pane.
    contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    return contentPane;
}

/** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = Menu.class.getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}


private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("BlockBreaker");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    Menu demo = new Menu();
    frame.setJMenuBar(demo.createMenuBar());
    frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

    //Display the window.
    frame.setSize(450, 260);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is how i imagined it in my mind:

```
        menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
            KeyEvent.VK_1, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        menuItem.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
            "This doesn't really do anything");
        menu.add(menuItem);

        menuItem = new MouseAction(MouseEvent.PRESS_LMB)
            if (PRESS_LMB.menuItem("New Game")) {
                start Gameplay.java;
            }
```

Comment: `addActionListener()` method on menu item should help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AbstractAction` class with your `JMenuItem` as below.

Replace your line of code:

```
menuItem = new JMenuItem("New Game", KeyEvent.VK_T);
```

By:

```
menuItem = new JMenuItem((new AbstractAction("New Game") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.print("clicked");
    }
}));
```

Comment: So basicly you want me to trash this one and merge the whole thing to game class and not make separate menu class?

Comment: While i was waiting answer i tried to make MouseEvent system so that the menu recognizes that i have pressed the button and then likn that action to the game class.

Comment: It helped little but didn't solve my problem yet. I edited my question so that there is my vision how it might go.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it gives error that says that my program doesnt recognize AbstractAction even after i have imported the javax.swing.AbstractAction. Do i need to have Abstract class?

Comment: use import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

Answer (score 0):

- Use separate name for different game menu otherwise you can't add diffrent action to them.
- Action performed using anonymous class or ActionListener. I'm showing for anonymous class.

See This for more Information: [How to use JMenu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)

> Using anonymous class:

```
final JMenuItem newGame;
newGame = new JMenuItem("New Game",
                         KeyEvent.VK_T);
menu.add(newGame);
newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 100);
        frame.setTitle("Game on Fire");
        frame.show();
    }
});
```

> Using ActionListener:

```
public YourClass implements ActionListener, ItemListener {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //...Get information from the action event...
    //...Display it in the text area...
}
}
```

If you want to run game on same window, use JPanel inside `actionPerformed`. Here is an Example:

```
public class GameClass extends JPanel{
    ///Game Logic Here
}
```

then add this too your `actionPerformed`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    GameClass game = new GameClass();
    menuPanel.setVisible(false); /// menuPanel is a selection window.
    mainPanel.add(game); // Now add your Game Window to same Frame.     
}
```